# Problems with the ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh, vscode-remote, macos-sonoma

recently my ssh key stop to working and I'm not being able push files to GitHub. When I try I get the following message:

> no such identity: /.../.../.ssh/id_ed25519s: No such file or directory
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.

It is weird because it stopped working out of nowhere. My computer is a MacBook m1 and I'm using the MacOS Sonoma@14.2.1

I follow several tutorials like this on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TviP5rCZiy0 and none of them works. I've no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: The message says what the problem is: SSH is looking for `/.../.../.ssh/id_ed25519s` but that file path is invalid. Do you have an `~/.ssh/config` defining that?

Comment: I wrote /.../.../.ssh/id_ed25519s: with '...' instead of the name of the directory justo to not show my directory tree. What really appears is:

no such identity: /Users/mack.ssh/id_ed25519s: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I figured you were using the ellipsis there, but the problem is the same: you've specified a bad path someplace. Is there a slash between `mack` and `.ssh` in the specified path? Does the key's filename really have `s` at the end?

Comment: Yes, there is a slash. The path is /Users/mack/.ssh/config, I wrote wrong when I answer you, I'm sorry. I got the error, the file did not end with 's'. A change it and now it is working. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -1):

Can you ping github.com? When I had problems with my ssh key it gave me a different error. It could be a network issue.

If you can open github on your browser, go to "Settings" and check your keys there, or access token on "Developer settings". Are there any new error messages there?